# Custom User System in Symfony?

Tags: php, system, symfony

Hello im new to Symfony and i have a question.
I already build a User Authentification following the Documentation.

```
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User


class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
```

So i have created a User Entity, the provider etc. my question is if its necessary to use this or can i just create a user system like User Database -> Login -> create Token, Session etc. without the Provider and the Security System in Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for sure, but it makes no sense. If you use the Symfony full stack framework you should use its features. If you dont want to use such basic fetaures dont use the full stack framework. Use the single symfony components and pick only the parts you need. Like the Routing component or others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But there is another question, when i login through the Login Form in dev mode, i can see my userdata in the toolbar, does that mean anything or is it just to display the Session? And is it safe to switch prod mode then?

Comment: The Toolbar is only for debugging purposes and will never be shown in the prod mode. You can see this in your AppKernel.php the WebProfilerBundle is only included in the dev or test mode.